# jQuery ^= vs |=. Unnecessary?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

```
jQuery attributeContainsPrefix [name^="value"]
```

vs

```
attributeStartsWith [name|="value"]
```

What the practical difference?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[**Attribute Contains Prefix Selector** in the Manual](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-prefix-selector/):

> Selects elements that have the
>   specified attribute with a value
>   either equal to a given string or
>   starting with that string **followed by
>   a hyphen (-)**.
>
> **This selector was introduced into the
>   CSS specification to handle language
>   attributes**.

That means it will match `en` and `en-US` but will not match `entanglement` like the other would. And this is not only good for languages, but anything that can be **prefixed**.